# Как использовать UV координаты в OpenGL вместе с Index Buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, index, текстура

Я пытаюсь отрисовать куб с помощью Index Buffer. То есть у меня есть 8 точек и индексный буфер, который показывает в каком порядке нужно отрисовывать эти точки, чтобы из треугольников получился куб. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
float positions[] = {
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //0
     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //1
    -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f, //2
     0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f, //3

    -0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f, //4
     0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f, //5
    -0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f, //6
     0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f, //7
};
unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    5, 6, 7,

    1, 5, 3,
    5, 3, 7,
    0, 4, 2,
    4, 2, 6,

    4, 5, 0,
    5, 0, 1,
    6, 7, 2,
    7, 2, 3
};
/* ... пропускаю в данном примере подготовку и передачу в OpenGL всех данных ибо это не относится к проблеме*/

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr));
```

И все работает. Но после я решил натянуть текстуры с использованием индексного буфера и столкнулся с тем что не получается ассоциировать каждую вершину куба с одной единственной позицией на двумерной текстуре, потому как для каждой отдельной грани (состоящей из двух треугольников) нужны разные координаты текстур и в таком случае использовать индексы для отрисовки не получается. Ибо если добавить UV координаты рядом с обычными и попробовать отрисовать куб, то получится что-то вроде этого:

```
float positions[] = {     
          //Pos            //UV
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 1.f, //0
     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   1.f, 1.f, //1
    -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f, //2
     0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   1.f, 0.f, //3

    -0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 1.f, //4
     0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 1.f, //5
    -0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 0.f, //6
     0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 0.f  //7
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    5, 6, 7,

    1, 5, 3,
    5, 3, 7,
    0, 4, 2,
    4, 2, 6,

    4, 5, 0,
    5, 0, 1,
    6, 7, 2,
    7, 2, 3
};
/* ... пропускаю в данном примере подготовку и передачу в OpenGL всех данных ибо это не относится к проблеме*/

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так как в OpenGL я новичок, то не знаю как это сделать правильно.
Можно конечно плюнуть и не использовать индексы и просто описать все треугольники по отдельности как-то так:

```
float positions[] = {
// Position             UV    
-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 1.f,
-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,
 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,

 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   1.f, 0.f,

-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 1.f,
 0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
-0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,

-0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,
 0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 0.f,

 0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 1.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,

 0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 0.f,

-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 1.f,
-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,

-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,
-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
-0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 0.f,

 0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 1.f,
-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,

 0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,
 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   1.f, 0.f,

-0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   0.f, 1.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,

-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   0.f, 0.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,   1.f, 1.f,
 0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,   1.f, 0.f,
};
/* ... пропускаю в данном примере подготовку и передачу в OpenGL всех данных ибо это не относится к проблеме*/

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36));
```

И на выходе получается абсолютно правильный и ожидаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но к сожалению, код становится более загромаждённым и приходится хранить гораздо больше данных, чем при использовании индексного буфера. Можно ли как-то передавать разные UV координаты для отдельных граней и при этом всё ещё использовать индексный буфер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае, одна вершина - одна UV координата. Если вам нужно разбивать/дублировать UV, то и вершины придется разбить/продублировать.

Куб, это ярчайший пример необходимости дублирования вершин из-за UV развертки - (8 вершин превращаются в 24 (что всё ещё капельку лучше, чем просто треугольники, с которыми будет 36 вершин). Для других моделей и форм всё гораздо лучше. Так что не забрасывайте индексы, они вам еще пригодятся )